# Callback function in an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to have a call back function on a directive I wrote, without creating an isolated scope. The directive simply makes the element resizeable, and thus doesn't need a separate scope (and it's desirable NOT to have isolated scope in this case, I think).

What is the best way to do this? I tried,

```
.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.myFunc = function () {
        console.log("test");
    };
})
.directive('resizeable', function ($document, $parse) {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {
        var func = $parse(attr.onFunc);
    }
 }
```

with

```
<div class="main" resizeable="" on-Func="myFunc()">
```

How to do this?

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcorat/Lj95P).

Comment: short answer is call ```func(scope);``` in your directive, see my full answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, here is what I'd do:

```
.directive('resizeable', ['$document', '$parse', function ($document, $parse) {
    return {
      link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var func = $parse($attrs.resizeable);

        // do stuff...

        func($scope);
       }
    };
 }]);
```

And the HTML would be:

```
<div data-resizeable="myFunc()"></div>
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/as6Tylj0zPpjVsUaDDC6?p=preview

Comment: thx, it works, i just had forgotten `ng-` in `ng-controller`, and passing `scope` was the only thing that was missing from my ex.

Answer (score 0):

```
on-Func="myFunc"
```

Without parenthesis. And in the directive:

```
var func = scope[attr.onFunc];
```

The directive is in the same scope as the controller. So you can directly refernece the function.